# How to prove $A \bigcap B$ is closed and bounded interval if given A&B are both closed and bounded intervals?

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove $A \bigcap B$ is closed and bounded interval if given A&B are both closed and bounded intervals?

I have proved that $A \bigcap B$ is bounded, but I have no idea how to prove it is closed and is an interval.

Does anyone could help me? Thanks!

Comment: Have you studied about limit points?

Comment: Do singleton sets and the empty set count as intervals?

Comment: Thanks for reminding that limit cannot be used here.I need to prove it use definition.

Comment: You can write $A = [a_1,a_2]$ and $B = [b_1,b_2]$. Then what is $A \cap B$? You can write it explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Let $A=[a_0,a_1]$ and $B=[b_0,b_1]$. Consider $\max\{a_0,b_0\}$ and $\min\{a_1,b_1\}$.

Comment: Then $A \bigcap B=[\max\{a_0,b_0\},\min\{a_1,b_1\}]$ ,but how can I show it is an interval? In fact, I don't know what I need to do if I want to show something is an interval.

Comment: @user133140: By the usual definition anything of the form $[u,v]$ is an interval, empty if $u>v$ and degenerate if $u=v$. Are you using some other definition? I can think of one that you *might* be using.

Comment: So, I just need to show that everything in $A \bigcap B$ is also in $[\max\{a_0,b_0\},\min\{a_1,b_1\}]$ and everything in $[\max\{a_0,b_0\},\min\{a_1,b_1\}]$ is also in $A \bigcap B$ ?

Comment: @user133140: That should do it, yes.

Comment: I got it, thanks very much!

Comment: @user133140: You’re very welcome!